# nhibernate : saving and retrieving a file to/from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I want to save PDF files in mssql using nhibernate. How do i go about it.

I read little bit about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098266/how-do-i-get-fluent-nhibernate-to-create-a-varbinarymax-field-in-sql-server), it tells that you can create a type to save the file as :

```
Map(x => x.Bytes)
  .CustomSqlType("VARBINARY (MAX) FILESTREAM")
  .Length(2147483647)
```

but I am still not able to understand what should be c# type of the field & and if its not FileInfo/FileStream then how to read write to that field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DB type Varbinary, has its C# representation `byte[]`

```
public virtual MyFile byte[] { get; set; }
```

Based on app type *(e.g. web with ASP.NET Web API)* we can provide *"download"* functionality like

```
protected virtual HttpResponseMessage Download(string fileName, string contentType
    , byte[] data)
{
    var path = fileName;
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
    result.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; fileName=" + path);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Well... answer is you can. But I would say why.. `byte[]` is really good enough for us. Because we can serialize it for any purposes *later*. I mean, if you really want to do some trick, do it like: 1) map **protected** `byte[]` property 2) create **public** property consuming that field and presenting it as ... filestream. Example of the techinque: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24052062/1679310

Comment: so you mean using get/set we should create/return fileInfo?

Comment: If you really need.. I would go this way. But my approach is: keep it `byte[]` as long as possible. Only *(finally)* on the service API (web api, asp.net mvc, routine...) just there convert it... Does it help?

Comment: Good luck with NHibernate sir, it is amazing tool ;)

Comment: @radim-kolher can you please have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686494/nhibernate-read-write-list-of-string) whenever you have time...

Comment: I saw this question, but did not have enough courage to tell you: I would not go this way... Why? I will give a comment there

Comment: @radhim-kohler i m still waiting :)

Comment: @harish, I gave you my view in a comment below of your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26686494/1679310)