# Use timestamp for versioning in NHibernate

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, oracle, nhibernate

I have a problem .I want to use version in NHibernate. This is work when I write below code but I want to use `timestamp` instead of `int` .

```
[Class(Table="COMMENTS")]
public class Comment {
   private int version;
   [Versioning]
   public virtual int Version {
      get { return version; }
      set { version = value; } 
  }
}
```

```
<class name="Comment" table="COMMENTS">
   <id ... ></id>
   <version name="Version" column="VERSION" />
   ...
</class>
```

when I changed type of property display this error.

> InnerException:   {"Version Property must be int"}    System.Exception

please help me

Comment: what is displaying the error?

Comment: InnerException: {"Version Property must be int"} System.Exception

Comment: Here is how I do define it in the mapping and C# code - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24052062

Comment: I use that code but that doesn't work.

Comment: Show the code you tried when using `timestamp`.

Comment: I used this code `[Versioning]
   public virtual int Version {
      get { return version; }
      set { version = value; } 
  }`

Comment: That code is using `int`, post your code that throws the error.

Comment: And what is the sql table column data type of `VERSION`?

Comment: I want use datetime but It doesn't work.but it works with int datatype.